# Отрисовка текста в QRect

Tags: c++, qt

Есть окно с кастовыми диаграммами, в котором можно менять шаг сетки по времени и масштаб в пикселях:
[image: Окно с диграммами]
После каждого изменения происходит перерисовка диаграммы. Шкала времени и сама диаграмма — 2 разных виджета, помещённых на два разных скрола.

**Задача:** рисовать подпись вертикальных линий центрировано, и чтобы никто ни на кого не налезал.

Здесь же, на SO, подглядел решение, что можно узнать, сколько в пикселях будет занимать текст. А значит можно взять размер максимальной подписи и танцевать уже от него:

```
lastNumber = static_cast<unsigned int>(dialog->commonSAGridSpacing * 
width() / dialog->commonSAScale);
    QFont currentFont = _painter->font();
    QFontMetrics fm(currentFont);
    unsigned int size = static_cast<unsigned int>(fm.width(QString::number(lastNumber)));
```

Сама перерисовка шкалы с подписями:

```
unsigned int maxNumberSizePix = numbersSizePix(painter);
unsigned int separatorPX = 4;
unsigned int shift = (maxNumberSizePix + separatorPX) / dialog->commonSAScale + 1;
    for (unsigned int counter = dialog->commonSAScale; counter < static_cast<unsigned int>(width()); counter += dialog->commonSAScale * shift) {
        QRectF currentRect(counter - maxNumberSizePix / 2, 2, maxNumberSizePix, height() - 4);
        painter->drawText(currentRect,
                          Qt::AlignCenter,
                          QString::number(static_cast<int>(counter / dialog->commonSAScale * dialog->commonSAGridSpacing)));
    }
```

**Проблема:** почему-то возникают ситуации, когда числа (например, 5229 у верхней диаграммы) не влазят в свой QRect и происходит небольшое обрезание отображаемого.

Comment: Не понял, как вы определяете размер прямоугольника, вмещающего надпись. Решал аналогичную задачу для своего виджета рендеринга 2D графики, там много подводных камней

Comment: думаю, ты не учёл, что в твоём шрифте разные числа одинаковой длины занимают разное количество пикселей за счёт разности в размере цифр, кернинга и лигатур… самое простое и надёжное ИМХО — использовать моноспейсный шрифт… иначе — использовать самые широкие символы шрифта для подсчёта, сколько нужно пикселей (например все восьмёрки) + запас 10%… ещё можно посмотреть. сколько занимают все отображаемые числа и выбрать максимальное… а ещё в любом случае хорошо будет отдавать `drawText`'у весь прямоугольник с разделителями — ИМХО наползающие числа, конечно тоже неприятно. но лучше, чем обрезанные…

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, беру у painter текущий шрифт, считаю последнее число и замеряю через готовый метод его размер в пикселях

Comment: как именно вы считаете размер в пикселях? boundingRect ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, извиняюсь, добавил код. Через QFontMetrics

Comment: попробуйте действительно использовать `QPainter::boundingRect`, я через него делал, все отрабатывает как надо

Comment: Рисование графиков и шкал это такая большая тема, что по моему лучше использовать готовую Qwt, если только нет графиков с миллионами отсчетов, где могут начаться тормоза. Ну а если вручную, то да boundingRect оптимально

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему добавлением запаса к размеру `QRect`:

```
//  Функция отрисовки шкалы
void TimeScale::draw(QPainter *painter) {
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::NonCosmeticDefaultPen, true);
    QPen *pen = new QPen(Qt::black);
    pen->setWidth(1);
    painter->setPen(*pen);

    int maxNumberSizePix = static_cast<int>(1.15 * numbersSizePix(painter));
    int separatorPX = 6;

    int scale;
    double gridSpacing;
    if (commonType) {
        scale = static_cast<int>(dialog->commonSAScale);
        gridSpacing = dialog->commonSAGridSpacing;
    } else {
        scale = static_cast<int>(dialog->resultsSAScale);
        gridSpacing = dialog->resultsSAGridSpacing;
    }

     int shift = static_cast<int>(1.0 * (maxNumberSizePix + separatorPX) / scale) + 1;

    for (int counter = scale; counter < width(); counter += scale * shift) {
        QRectF currentRect(counter - maxNumberSizePix / 2, 2, maxNumberSizePix, height() - 4);
        painter->drawText(currentRect, Qt::AlignCenter, QString::number(static_cast<int>(gridSpacing * counter / scale)));
    }

    delete pen;
}


//  Размер последнего числа на шкале в пикселях
unsigned int TimeScale::numbersSizePix(QPainter *_painter) {
    unsigned int lastNumber = 0;
    if (commonType) {
        lastNumber = static_cast<unsigned int>(dialog->commonSAGridSpacing * width() / dialog->commonSAScale);
    } else {
        lastNumber = static_cast<unsigned int>(dialog->resultsSAGridSpacing * width() / dialog->resultsSAScale);
    }

    QFont currentFont = _painter->font();
    QFontMetrics fm(currentFont);

    return static_cast<unsigned int>(fm.width(QString::number(lastNumber)));
}
```